# Better way to find index of item in ArrayList?

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

For an Android app, I have the following functionality

```
private ArrayList<String> _categories; // eg ["horses","camels"[,etc]]

private int getCategoryPos(String category) {
    for(int i = 0; i < this._categories.size(); ++i) {
        if(this._categories.get(i) == category) return i;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Is that the "best" way to write a function for getting an element's position? Or is there a fancy shmancy native function in java the I should leverage?

Comment: This code is likely flawed: use of `==` will yield incorrect results in most cases.

Comment: Remember, you can't compare strings with '==', you have to use String.equals(String str)

Comment: @MrZander Sure you can compare them with `==` ... it just not be the right kind of comparison ;-)

Comment: You can tell I'm still new to Java.. is `String.equals` more like what a `===` might be in a language like JavaScript? eg. checks against value AND type?

Comment: **No.** `==` is *object-identity* and it means **"is the same object"**. (This view holds true for primitive values as well as reference types, if you consider there is only one number with the value 42 or char 'x', etc). `Object.equals` is a *virtual method* defined for all object instances and it means **"has the same value"**, as all class types extend Object, and should be used for all *object-equality* tests. **There are many questions at cover `==` vs `Object.equals` and this is a very important concept to understand!** For instance, this is false: `"hello" == new String("hello")`! Doh!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus and related questions.

Answer (score 212, accepted):

`ArrayList` has an [`indexOf()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-). Check the API for more, but here's how it works:

```
private ArrayList<String> _categories; // Initialize all this stuff

private int getCategoryPos(String category) {
  return _categories.indexOf(category);
}
```

`indexOf()` will return exactly what your method returns, fast.

Comment: It is no "fast"er in terms of complexity than the code posted, although it may be implemented more efficiently. Also, indexOf will react slightly differently here: the original code [incorrectly] uses `==` while indexOf uses `equals()`.

Comment: In fact, it's almost the same code exactly (at least in the Sun Java 6 code I have), except that they start it with an if-else branch that handles null separately.

Comment: It's wired old arrays and List<> have FindIndex() method but the API changes in the middle for ArrayList :D

Answer (score 17):

```
ArrayList<String> alphabetList = new ArrayList<String>();
alphabetList.add("A"); // 0 index
alphabetList.add("B"); // 1 index
alphabetList.add("C"); // 2 index
alphabetList.add("D"); // 3 index
alphabetList.add("E"); // 4 index
alphabetList.add("F"); // 5 index
alphabetList.add("G"); // 6 index
alphabetList.add("H"); // 7 index
alphabetList.add("I"); // 8 index

int position = -1;
position = alphabetList.indexOf("H");
if (position == -1) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Object not found in List");
} else {
    Log.i(TAG, "" + position);
}
```

**Output:** List Index : **7**

If you pass **H** it will return **7**, if you pass **J** it will return **-1** as we defined default value to -1.

**Done**

Comment: How i can make the vise versa of this, for your solution your input is **H**  and you get the position of  **H**, Suppose if my input is the Index of **7** how i can get the the String value of that index. Thank You

Comment: @JimaleAbdi Do yourArrayList.get(7). 7 is your position.

Answer (score 7):

If your `List` is sorted and has good random access (as `ArrayList` does), you should look into `Collections.binarySearch`. Otherwise, you should use `List.indexOf`, as others have pointed out.

But your algorithm is sound, fwiw (other than the `==` others have pointed out).

Answer (score 4):

Java API specifies two methods you could use: `indexOf(Object obj)` and `lastIndexOf(Object obj)`. The first one returns the index of the element if found, -1 otherwise. The second one returns the last index, that would be like searching the list backwards.

Answer (score 3):

There is indeed a fancy shmancy native function in java you should leverage.

ArrayList has an instance method called

`indexOf(Object o)`

(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

You would be able to call it on `_categories` as follows:

`_categories.indexOf("camels")`

I have no experience with programming for Android - but this would work for a standard Java application.

Good luck.

Comment: native function implies C\C++ to me..Just saying.

Answer (score 2):

the best solution here

```
class Category(var Id: Int,var Name: String)
arrayList is Category list
val selectedPositon=arrayList.map { x->x.Id }.indexOf(Category_Id)
spinner_update_categories.setSelection(selectedPositon)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use indexOf() method to find first occurrence of the element in the collection.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to find the position of item in the list is by using Collections interface,

Eg,

```
List<Integer> sampleList = Arrays.asList(10,45,56,35,6,7);
Collections.binarySearch(sampleList, 56);
```

Output : 2