# Find position of specific element in arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a class "Student".That stores the information of students name age mark etc. I'm using it in arraylist. Here I want to know the position of specific student. Is there any methods to find it or I have to use "for" .please help me?

```
Class student{
     String name; 
     Int age; 
      Int mark1; 
     Int mark2; 
     Public class student(String name,Int age, Int mark1, Int mark2){
      this.name=name;
      ...
      ...
          }
       
        }
    In the main function {
      Arraylist<student> ar=new Arraylist<student>();
      //Added some students detail using add method //
```

Then I have to find a position of the student using his name.

Comment: See [`ArrayList#indexOf(Object o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Better way to find index of item in ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439037/better-way-to-find-index-of-item-in-arraylist)

Comment: Indexof requires a object. Should the object contain name,age,mark1,mark2 or Is it enough to have a name only? Because I'm asking what if I have students name only.

Answer (score 0):

The Java List interface has

> int indexOf(Object o)

> > Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element.

But that would require you to pass in a *Student* object to search for.

Thus: you have to somehow iterate the list, and do compare "manually".

Of course, there are many different ways to do that. Using *streams* for example, you might be able to write very concise code do that. But for newbies, just go step by step. First do a normal for loop, then try the "for each" version, then look into streams.

Comment: Thank You  I'll Try Using For Loop

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indexOf` method defined in the `List<T>` interface as mentioned before.
Its signature looks like:

```
int indexOf(Object o);
```

But you'll need to override the `equals` and `hashCode` methods of `Object` class in your `Student` class to use `indexOf`.

For example in

```
class Student {

//... fields, methods and constructors, you already defined


  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (this == o) return true;
      if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
      Student student = (Student) o;
      return age == student.age &&
              mark1 == student.mark1 &&
              mark2 == student.mark2 &&
              Objects.equals(name, student.name);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
      return Objects.hash(name, age, mark1, mark2);
  }
}
```